# Special Questions

Tags: questions, singular-vs-plural

1)The children always want some candies.
a)Who always want some candies?
b)Who always wants some candies?

2) The children are busy.
a) Who is busy?
b) Who are busy?
 Which of these answers are correct?As I know special question requires singular verbs, but I want to make sure.

Comment: What’s a “special question”?

Comment: Technically, because we know the questions, "Who are busy?" and "Who always want some candies" are correct, but generally they would sound a bit awkward—especially if you didn't know the answer was plural.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what the context is, but please consider this (everything that follows is grammatically correct):

1. Children always want candy.
2. Who always wants candy?
3. The children are busy.
4. Who is busy?

In 1 and 2 it is implied that *all* children always want candy.

3 and 4 are about a specific group of children. They're busy in some other room. You walk into the living room, greet the parents, and then ask "Where are the kids?" Meaning, their kids, plus, perhaps, some of their friends. And the parents reply, "The children are busy right now."

Comment: Which is used depends entirely on context. A teacher walks into room and asks *Who wants a book?*. The children all want books. But the head-teacher, trying to ascertain which class needs books asks the teacher *Who want books?* - meaning *which children want books ?*

Comment: @WS2: The teacher would then ask, "Which of you morons want books?"